# In-app purchases: Types of products

Tags: in-app-purchase

Please, help me to clarify purchases types. 
I have an ionic project, where a user has a possibility to post to feed. But he/she has to pay for each news he/she posts. 
I know that purchases are of three types: consumable, non-consumable and subscriptions.

I cant understand **what is the type of such kind of purchases**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would be a consumable type as you are paying every time you post.

Good description from a previous post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21251768/5270656

Ref: itunesconnect.apple.com

Everything is here:

> #### Consumable (pay everytime)
>
> A consumable In-App Purchase must be purchased every time
>   the user downloads it. One-time services, such as fish food in a
>   fishing app, are usually implemented as consumables.
>
> #### Select Non-Consumable (one time payment)
>
> Non-consumable In-App Purchases only need to be
>   purchased once by users. Services that do not expire or decrease with
>   use are usually implemented as non-consumables, such as new race
>   tracks for a game app.
>
> #### Select Auto-Renewable Subscriptions (will deduct money from your credit card on a cycle complete)
>
> Auto-renewable Subscriptions allow
>   the user to purchase updating and dynamic content for a set duration
>   of time. Subscriptions renew automatically unless the user opts out,
>   such as magazine subscriptions.
>
> #### Select Free Subscription (no payment and is still visible even you did not submitted your account detail to itunes connect)
>
> Free subscriptions are a way for developers
>   to put free subscription content in Newsstand. Once a user signs up
>   for a free subscription, it will be available on all devices
>   associated with the user’s Apple ID. Note that free subscriptions do
>   not expire and can only be offered in Newsstand-enabled apps.
>
> #### Select Non-Renewing (need to renew manually)
>
> Subscription Non-Renewing Subscriptions allow the
>   sale of services with a limited duration. Non-Renewing Subscriptions
>   must be used for In-App Purchases that offer time-based access to
>   static content. Examples include a one week subscription to voice
>   guidance feature within a navigation app or an annual subscription to
>   online catalog of archived video or audio.

Comment: thank you! I was confused because the user really doesn't download anything, he/she just pays for what he/she does..